# How do i remove a stripped crank?

Tags: crankset, tools, stuck

I found an old abandoned 1999 diamondback outlook that im trying to repair. The crank is bent as well as the front chainring. I bought a universal crank remover from Parktool. I unscrewed and removed the crank bolts. Then i screwed in the crank remover. It worked great for the non-drive side. However, when I tried to use it on the drive side I wasn't successful at all! I couldn't even screw the crank remover into the crank arm because it's so badly stripped and even has a couple of chips in it. How can I re-thread or remove the crank and chainset to replace them?

Comment: Well sounds like the crank is trashed. I'd use a hacksaw.

Comment: Aside - check if the axle is square taper or one of the round standards like octalink.   Usinng a square crank puller on octalink will damage things - your universal tool should have some kind of spreader-pad to press on the end of the axle shaft/spindle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 - try and back out the drive side cup while working around the crank.   Since you've removed the NDS crank and cup, the whole mess should be able to come out the drive side and into the recycle.   Note the drive side cup is left-hand thread.

Option 2 - Use a hacksaw or a grinder with a cutoff wheel, to cut the axle between the frame and right crankarm.  Avoid damaging the frame, but the cup should provide enough protection. When it comes off, salvage anything you can then to the recycle bin.   Then you can access the drive side cup easier.

You're going to need a new bottom bracket assembly, which probably means a cartridge.  You also need replacement crank arms to match, and possibly chainrings if the old ones can't be straightened.  The old pedals may still be serviceable though.

Sounds like a fun project !   Feel free to include photos with your question, or progress photos in an answer of your own.

Comment: The bottom bracket spindle is incredibly hard. It's much easier to cut the soft, usually alu, crank

Comment: @Noise true, are you suggesting carving through the crank where it meets the axle, until it comes off ?

Comment: I make a deep gouge along one of the edges of the spindle, then beat the crank until it cracks and falls off, but I might have a more violent temprement than you

Comment: @Noise that's a good idea - can you add it as an answer?   Do you use a grinder, hacksaw, or just go caveman with a hammer and cold chisel ?

Answer (score 3):

Unior (and I think a couple others) makes a tapered crank remover for trashed crank threads.

https://uniortools.com/eng/product/1662-4-tapered-crank-puller#88225

[image]

Comment: I'm looking at this tool now and sent an inquiry to company. I don't think it works on square crankset but will see what their response is